# Changing limits in triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I am new to calculus and would love some feedback regarding the following question + my answer. Many thanks in advance!

$I=\int^9_0dx\int^{3-\sqrt{x}}_0dz\int^{z}_{0}f(x,y,z)dy$

We want to change it to
$\int^?_?dx\int^?_?dy\int^{?}_{?}f(x,y,z)dz$

What are the limits that are currently marked by "?"

a. $\int^3_0dx\int^{3-\sqrt{y}}_0dy\int^{y}_{0}f(x,y,z)dz$

b. $\int^9_0dx\int^{3-\sqrt{x}}_0dy\int^{3-\sqrt{x}}_{y}f(x,y,z)dz$

c. $\int^9_0dx\int^{3}_0dy\int^{\sqrt{3-x}}_{0}f(x,y,z)dz$

d. $\int^9_0dx\int^{x}_0dy\int^{3-\sqrt{x}}_{0}f(x,y,z)dz$

e. none of the above

I reasoned it should be d, as

$y\leq z\leq\sqrt{3-x}$

$0\leq y \leq3$

$0 \leq x \leq 9$,

but I am really unsure about the methodology, as this was never taught in class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to describe$$\{(x,y,z): 0 \le x \le 9, 0 \le z \le 3 - \sqrt{x}, 0 \le y \le z\}$$

We just want to change the order of $y$ and $z$.
Let's express bounds on $y$ using $x, $ that is  $0 \le y \le z \le 3 -\sqrt{x}$.

$$0 \le y \le 3-\sqrt{x}$$

Let's express bounds on $z$ using $x$ and $y$.

$$y \le z \le 3-\sqrt{x}$$

Hence the answer should be $b$.